# Why is entity references still be included in properties is their a better way to achieve this code

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

As you can see below im going through the property of an entity to get the field names and values for an audit trail system however its bringing back the references to the object that is passed ie careerReference=System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1

absanal=HallmarkSolutions.PAMS.Interop.EntityFramework.AbsenceSicknessReason

How to I modify the code below to be more efficent and also ignore the navigation propertyes

```
public  string ObjectToNotes(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "Value can not be null or Nothing!");
            }               
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Type t = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
            List<StandardLookup> absenceReasons = pamsContext.GetAbsenceReasons();            
            for (int index = 0; index < pi.Length; index++)
            {
                if (pi[index].PropertyType != typeof(EntityKey) && pi[index].PropertyType != typeof(EntityObject) && pi[index].PropertyType != typeof(EntityReference))
                {
                    string message;
                    message = pi[index].Name.ToString() + "  " + pi[index].PropertyType.ToString();
                      if (pi[index].Name=="reason")
                         sb.Append("reason=" + pamsContext.GetAbsenceReasonsDescription(Convert.ToInt32(pi[index].GetValue(obj, null))));
                    else
                    sb.Append(pi[index].Name + "=" + pi[index].GetValue(obj, null) + Environment.NewLine);


                    if (index < pi.Length - 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }

            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you may ignore objects derived from `EntityObject`:

```
if (typeof(EntityObject).IsAssignableFrom(pi[index].PropertyType))
    continue;
```

This won't skip, for example, `AbsenceSicknessReasonId` property (it's just an `Int32` and it may not be obvious to discriminate from another *normal* property). You may do it little bit better with a very naive assumption: an Id property will (almost always) have its related navigation property.

```
if (pi[index].Name.EndsWith("Id"))
{
    string navigationProperty =
        pi[index].Name.Substring(0, pi[index].Name.Length - 2);

    if (pi.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == navigationProperty) != null)
        continue;
}
```

As you can see this is a pretty weak and naive assumption but it should work in many (most?) cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Entity Context? If so, you can get the property names of your entity by calling

```
List<string> propNames = context.Entry(yourEntry).OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToList()
```

Then go through the list of propert ynames to get your values, e.g.

```
context.Entry(yourEntry).Property(propNames[0]).CurrentValue
```

Navigational properties are not included in the list.